# I develop a project on GAE: how do I download the last deploy my colleagues made

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-7

I'm getting started with Google App Engine, and just got my first invite to a project that has already been started by someone else. How do I download the code to start editing it? (I do see the project in the `launcher` in red)

If it has any importance, my permission is `Developer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it. First of all `developers` can only download they're won code, my status had to be upgraded to `owner` and then according to [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Source_Code) from the google documentation all you have to do is:

1. Open console and go to the target directory
2. run the script: `appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>`
3. Enter my Email & password

Wait for the download to finish :-)

- To get the `<your_app_id>` and `<your_app_version>` - Go to [appengine](https://appengine.google.com/) -> click on your project -> from left panel click `Versions` -> from the URL copy the value of `app_id` and `version_id`.
- For `<output-dir>` just specify the directory on your machine, or `.` if its the current.